# Xamarin - Why picker does not show items?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

** Editor VS 2013
** Target: iOS 6.0

I am exprimenting with a picker. The picker definition as follows

```
var picker = new Picker() {
    Titel = "Test",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
};
picker.Items.Add("AAA");
picker.Items.Add("DDDD");
Content = new StackLayout {
    Children = { picker }
};
```

when I run this code, I can see the 'Test' show up and when I click it, I do not see any of the items rather it shows just 'Done'. Is there anything am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, it is indeed a bug in Xamarin. I was able to run the same code under iPhone 4 & 5 but it doesn't work in iPhone 6/6+ emulators.

Comment: Does it work on iOS 7 or iOS 8? Also, what phones/simulators are you trying it on?

Comment: It does not work on iPhone 6 - iOS 8, all the older ones it works.

Comment: OK I think you are confused between iOS and iPhone versions. iOS is the operating system running on the device. iOS 8 can be installed on iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, and 6/6+ (when you say you tried it under iOS 4 & 5 I think you mean iPhone 4 and iPhone 5). You need to clarify _both_ the iOS version and iPhone model. Eg. iPhone 5 running iOS 8 or iPhone 4 running iOS 7. We need to be able to determine if this is a bug with the SDK/bindings or the specific implementation for a particular phone model.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes you are correct on the explanation.

Comment: For me, it is not working on the simulator for any phone with ios8. This is new, it was working under 7.  It does, however, work on my iPhone 6 running iOS8

Answer (score 0):

Basically the picker is not shown, and not braught to the front, after you have created the item, just focus on the picker.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    if (picker.IsFocused)
        picker.Unfocus();

    picker.Focus();
});
```

This answer was taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42017240/1799272