# Trigger Xamarin.Forms Picker

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can i Trigger a Picker programatically?

I would like a button beside the picker that indicates that the picker is a clickable "dropdown". But how could I open the picker when the button is clicked?

Comment: BTW, if Picker class isn't providing what you want, a more flexible approach is seen in "Action Sheet" sample in [Allan Ritchie - "ACR.UserDialogs" nuget src](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs). Defined via a descriptive config object in StandardViewModel.CreateActionSheetCommand. On UWP, this is based on [UWP XAML ContentDialog class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog). On iOS and Android, appropriate native controls are built.

Comment: ... I'm not sure why that nuget doesn't instead build on [Xamarin Forms `ContentView` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentview?view=xamarin-forms) - doing so would make it easier to generate custom cross-platform dialogs.  I mention the UWP implementation above, because it looks like something that could be adapted to use X-Forms views w/i a contentview. See `UserDialogsImpl` under Platforms / UWP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can name the picker (e.g. myPicker) and call its Focus event. Do make sure that you're on the main thread at the time you're calling myPicker.Focus()

Comment: I originally got my code working by using this answer here.  Unfortunately, I have just noticed that this has stopped working.  Calling picker.Focus() now seems to do nothing on both iOS and Windows Phone (unable to test Android).  Does anyone know if anything has changed in Xamarin.Forms to break this functionality?

Comment: your "make sure you're on the main thread" point helped me in solving a bug where picker won't show up after displayalert

Comment: On iOS, `picker.Focus()` is working again. Also works on Android. I haven't tested on UWP.

Answer (score 12):

As @Hutjepower and [this xamarin forums post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59573/problem-reliably-giving-focus-to-a-picker-from-a-button-click-handler-on-ios?) mentions, the following code *should* work:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    if (yourPicker.IsFocused)
        yourPicker.Unfocus();

    yourPicker.Focus();
});
```

However I have found that it does not currently work on Windows 8.1 and UWP apps, at least in the latest 2.3.4-pre1 version of Xamarin.Forms. I haven't tested it on any phone/tablet devices yet though. Hopefully this bug will get fixed up in a later release. I have created [a bug report for this problem](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52266).

Comment: Checking for focus and then unfocusing solved the issue for me. I was already calling `.focus()` without triggering the `Picker` to open.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not; the inner workings of the picker are almost entirely in the renderers and are not exposed via an API.

Comment: Picker is just a label with tap gesture from what I know. There is a focus event as well that is public.